# Curl,save all responses in one file

Tags: curl, sh

How to save all the responses to a single file, one by one?

```
curl -i "www.google.com"> result.txt 
curl -i "www.ask.com"> result.txt
```

In one file(result.txt), I would like to receive:

www.google.com - HTTP/1.1 200 OK

www.ask.com    - HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

Use this shell syntax:

```
(curl -Is http://example.com ; curl -Is http://example2.com) > results.txt
```

Or if you just want the fist line `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`:

```
(for url in \
    http://example.com \
    http://example2.com ; do
    echo -n "$url - " ; curl -Is "$url" |head -1
done) >results.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I wanted to do the same thing with this: 1- curl -i -XGET  -H"Accept: application/xml" -H"token:`curl -d"user=user1&pass=pass" $SERVER/data/login`" $SERVER/data/log >
..........................2- curl -i -XGET  -H"Accept: application/xml" -H"token:`curl -d"user=user1&pass=pass" $SERVER/data/login`" $SERVER/data/log > . As well as for: http://example.com, http://example2.com. There is such a possibility?

Comment: I would like to do the same only on this url: curl -i -XGET -H"Accept: application/xml" -H"token:curl -d"user=user1&pass=pass" $SERVER/data/login" $SERVER/data/log